# connect arrays with the foreign id from another array angular ts

Tags: angular, typescript

I have these json Objects in the InMemoryDataService (mock server) and services.ts for its object to getAll the elements of them (in the shop.service.ts, etc).
I want to show in a html page instead of productId and shopId, the product.name and the shop.name with the particular id of products and shops.  How can I do it?

```
 createDb() {
const prices = [
  { id: 11, price: 3.40, dateFrom:'12/3/19', dateTo: '15/3/19', productId: 3,shopId: 4},
  { id: 12, price: 5.40, dateFrom:'6/3/19', dateTo:'22/3/19', productId: 1,shopId: 4}, 
  { id: 13, price: 8.00, dateFrom:'21/3/19', dateTo:'23/4/19', productId: 2,shopId: 2},
  { id: 14, price: 6.30, dateFrom:'17/3/19', dateTo:'23/3/19', productId: 3,shopId: 3},
];

const products = [
  {id:1, name: 'Barilia', description: 'Good Coffee', category :'Espresso', tags:['Coffe','Espresso'], withdrawn: false},
  {id:2, name: 'Nespresso', description: 'Good Coffee', category :'Espresso', tags:['Coffe','Espresso'], withdrawn: false},
  {id:3, name: 'Island', description: 'Good Coffee', category :'Cappuchino', tags:['Coffe','Cappuchino'], withdrawn: false},
  {id:4, name: 'Lavanca', description: 'Good Coffee', category :'Espresso', tags:['Coffe','Espresso'], withdrawn: false}
];

 const shops = [ 
  { id: 1, name: 'Coffee Island',address: 'Agioi Theodwroi 10,Petroupoli,14432', Ing: 30.5 , Iat: 54.44,tags ['Coffee','Espresso'],withdrawn:false},
  { id: 2, name: 'Coffee Bear',address: 'Valsamou 42,Kifisia,14675', Ing: 32.5 , Iat: 60.43,tags:['Coffee','Espresso'], withdrawn:false },
  { id: 3, name: 'Coffee Lab',address: 'Thiseas 10,Marousi,31313', Ing: 29.5 , Iat: 50.44, tags:['Coffee','Espresso'], withdrawn:false },
  { id: 4, name: 'Starbucks',address: 'Kifisias 7,Kifisia,12345', Ing: 27.8 , Iat: 37.9,tags:['Coffee','Espresso'], withdrawn:false  }
];

return {products,prices,shops};
```

Comment: unclear what you actually want to do. Do you want to generate a new json with `product.name` instead of `product.Id` with prices json?

Comment: yes sorry for my question form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can loop through your prices json and add those name property like this

Add product name & shop name property

```
prices.forEach(x=>{
    x['productName']= products.find(y=>y.id === x.productId).name;
    x['shopName']= shops.find(y=>y.id === x.shopId).name;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Search through your array of products with the id.

```
const product = products.find(product => product.id === productId)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I should write that in my component when I take the elements of all arrays with particular separate methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you have them loaded asynchronously, you can use getter to get the data, like this

```
    private prices = [
        { id: 11, price: 3.40, dateFrom: '12/3/19', dateTo: '15/3/19', productId: 3, shopId: 4 },
        { id: 12, price: 5.40, dateFrom: '6/3/19', dateTo: '22/3/19', productId: 1, shopId: 4 },
        { id: 13, price: 8.00, dateFrom: '21/3/19', dateTo: '23/4/19', productId: 2, shopId: 2 },
        { id: 14, price: 6.30, dateFrom: '17/3/19', dateTo: '23/3/19', productId: 3, shopId: 3 },
    ];

    private products = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Barilia', description: 'Good Coffee', category: 'Espresso', tags: ['Coffe', 'Espresso'], withdrawn: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'Nespresso', description: 'Good Coffee', category: 'Espresso', tags: ['Coffe', 'Espresso'], withdrawn: false },
        { id: 3, name: 'Island', description: 'Good Coffee', category: 'Cappuchino', tags: ['Coffe', 'Cappuchino'], withdrawn: false },
        { id: 4, name: 'Lavanca', description: 'Good Coffee', category: 'Espresso', tags: ['Coffe', 'Espresso'], withdrawn: false }
    ];

    private shops = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Coffee Island', address: 'Agioi Theodwroi 10,Petroupoli,14432', Ing: 30.5, Iat: 54.44, tags: ['Coffee', 'Espresso'], withdrawn: false },
        { id: 2, name: 'Coffee Bear', address: 'Valsamou 42,Kifisia,14675', Ing: 32.5, Iat: 60.43, tags: ['Coffee', 'Espresso'], withdrawn: false },
        { id: 3, name: 'Coffee Lab', address: 'Thiseas 10,Marousi,31313', Ing: 29.5, Iat: 50.44, tags: ['Coffee', 'Espresso'], withdrawn: false },
        { id: 4, name: 'Starbucks', address: 'Kifisias 7,Kifisia,12345', Ing: 27.8, Iat: 37.9, tags: ['Coffee', 'Espresso'], withdrawn: false }
    ];

    get data() {
        return this.prices.reduce((sum, item) => {
            return [...sum, {
                ...item,
                shop: this.shops.find((shop) => shop.id === item.shopId),
                product: this.products.find((product) => product.id === item.productId),
            }];
        }, <any>[]);
    }
```

Comment: Now I have add the fuction getData() as  you wrote and I also wrote the command:    return {shops,prices,products,getData};  , should I make a new data.service.ts in order to take this data from mock server? What fuctions should I add in there?

Comment: It's up to you to write the service. I think it's better to have that service. Same with what you have here